# Metaplex CM Cannot Mint NFT - AnchorError caused by account: candy_guard. Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram

Tags: metaplex, candy-machine-v2, umi

I'm having trouble minting an NFT using **@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine@6.0.0**. Whenever I try to do so, I get the following error: *AnchorError caused by account: candy_guard. Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram*.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
const mint = async () => {
  if (!wallet?.connected || !candyMachine) {
    return;
  }

  const umi = createUmi(SOLANA_RPC_ENDPOINT)
    .use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet))
    .use(mplCandyMachine());

  const nftMint = generateSigner(umi);

  await transactionBuilder()
    .add(setComputeUnitLimit(umi, { units: 1_000_000 }))
    .add(
      mintV2(umi, {
        candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
        nftMint,
        collectionMint: candyMachine.collectionMint,
        collectionUpdateAuthority: candyMachine.authority,
        candyGuard: candyMachine.mintAuthority,
        mintArgs: {
          mintLimit: some({ id: 1 })
        }
      })
    )
    .sendAndConfirm(umi);
};
```

This is the error message that I'm receiving:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ProgramErrorNotRecognizedError: The program [mplCandyGuard] at address [Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g] raised an error that is not recognized by the programs registered on the SDK. Please check the underlying program error below for more details.

Source: Program > mplCandyGuard [Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g]

Caused By: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xbbf

Program Logs:
| Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
| Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success
| Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g invoke [1]
| Program log: Instruction: MintV2
| Program log: AnchorError caused by account: candy_guard. Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram. Error Number: 3007. Error Message: The given account is owned by a different program than expected.
| Program log: Left:
| Program log: 11111111111111111111111111111111
| Program log: Right:
| Program log: Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g
| Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g consumed 10260 of 1000000 compute units
| Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g failed: custom program error: 0xbbf

    at Object.resolveError (createDefaultProgramRepository.mjs:84:1)
    at Object.sendTransaction (createWeb3JsRpc.mjs:158:1)
    at async TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (TransactionBuilder.mjs:209:1)
    at async mint (cmProvider.tsx:84:19)
    at async handleMint (index.tsx:24:17)
```

Here are the dependencies:

```
"@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine": "^6.0.0",
"@metaplex-foundation/umi": "^0.8.10",
"@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults": "^0.8.10",
"@metaplex-foundation/umi-signer-wallet-adapters": "^0.8.10",
"@solana/spl-token": "^0.3.8",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.22",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.32",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.31",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.19.16",
"@solana/web3.js": "^1.76.0"
```

The Candy machine ID is **Ao9bam2dURrcbapnRg6kseAeAeaiCMnJGHncdnRCTSQ**.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

This issue is caused by the `candyGuard` account. According to the error logs, its program owner is invalid — i.e. it is not owned by the Candy Guard program you are sending the transaction to. More often than not, this will occur when the provided `candyGuard` account does not exist as its assigned program will be automatically set to the System program.

Since the `candyGuard` account is not explicitly provided in your code snippet, it will default to deriving its address using the provided `candyMachine` account as the base seed of its PDA.

If you created your `candyGuard` account using a different convention — e.g. by using another library or website — than the default value may be wrong.

### Solution

Providing the correct `candyGuard` account explicitly to the `mintV2` instruction should fix your issue.

Since it seems you are already fetching and decoding the data of your candy machine account, you may use the `mintAuthority` data attribute since it will always be equal to the address of the associated candy guard account when one is set.

```
mintV2(umi, {
  candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
  candyGuard: candyMachine.mintAuthority,
  // ...
});
```

### Disclaimer

This problem/solution statement assumes you are indeed guarding your candy machine using the Candy Guard program — which is the case 99% of the time. If you want to mint from a candy machine directly as its mint authority, you will need to use the `mintFromCandyMachineV2` instruction.

You can [read more about the minting process](https://developers.metaplex.com/candy-machine/mint) in the official Metaplex documentation.